# can't access Class method in Java

Tags: java, methods

Hi I have created the following class

```
public class Hour {

    private long mTime;
    private String mSummary;
    private double mTemparature;
    private String mIcon;


    public long getTime() {
        return mTime;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        mTime = time;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return mSummary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        mSummary = summary;
    }

}
```

And then in another java class I create an Hour array and I want to try to call the function setSummary, however it doesn't work:

```
  Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];

hours.setSummary(test);
```

it says can't resolve method setSummary.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hours` is an array not an instance of class `Hour` that is why you get compilation error. For invoking `setSummary()` you need to create an instance of `Hour` class. May be you wanted to do something like:

```
Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];
hours[0] = new Hour();
hours[0].setSummary(test);
```

*Note*: I assumed that `data.length()` is either of type `char`, `short`, `byte` or `int` and `data.length() > 0`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why? You mean `hours[0] = new Hour();` in the posted code isn't enough?

Comment: @MikeCAT gah - misread it. OK then... after having ensured that `data.length() > 0` :)

Comment: @AndyTurner ... and the type of `data.length()` is `int`, or at least not any of `long`, `double` or `float`.

Comment: @AndyTurner @MikeCAT Yes, `data.length() > 0`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`hours` is an array and there are little chance to have `setSummary`.

You may want something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    (hours[i] = new Hour()).setSummary(test);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Nant is correct. You want `hours[i].setSummary(test)`. If you want to apply this to everything in the array, use

```
for(Hour i : hours)
{
    i.setSummary(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hours is an array of type Hour. You can call methods on the individual elements e.g.

```
hours[0].setSummary(test);
```

but not on the array itself. To instantiate one Hour, just call new:

```
Hour hour = new Hour();
hour.setSummary(test);
```

Comment: `hours[0]` is `null` just after `Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];` assuming that `data.length()` is positive integer. Be careful for `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave `hours` is an array and an array doesn't expose the method `setSummary(String summary)`.

If you want to set the summary to all elements into the array try this :

```
Hour[] hours = new Hour[data.length()];
// fill your array here
for(Hour hour : hours){
    hour.setSummary(test);
}
```